# How to debug a python script without a project in PyDev?

Tags: pydev

I have a Python script that I wrote without creating a containing project. In PyDev, I know how to run and debug Python projects. But when I open this script in PyDev, I don't know how to run it or debug it, because it isn't associated with any project.

Comment: You could always create a dummy project to associate it with.

Comment: @K.Niemczyk IS that the only way? It seems overkill.

Comment: I believe so. That's fairly standard for Eclipse IDE plugins. For instance, I'm under the impression that you can't run compile/run a Java class without putting into a project first.

Comment: @K.Niemczyk : Which python IDE's allow you to debug scripts without a project?